# difference between "new Date(d)" and "new Date(+d)"

Tags: javascript, date

I have a query which I am facing in my code.

What is the difference between

```
new Date(d)
```

and

```
new Date(+d)
```

where `d=new Date();`

Comment: `+d` converts the date to an timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one returns the date string

```
Tue Jan 07 2014 11:37:28 GMT+0000 (locale)
```

the second should return the <s>unix</s> timestamp (in milliseconds)

```
1389091048652
```

if you log them, but the first is still a date object, while the second one is just a number.

Both are valid and can be passed back to `new Date()`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQeeg/1/)

Comment: The numerical representation of a JS date is *not* a unix timestamp. (seconds vs milliseconds).

Comment: @Tomalak - it's a timestamp, in milliseconds, from epoch

Comment: Correct. It's just not a *unix* timestamp (which by definition is seconds).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two lies in the operations performed:

```
new Date(date)
```

creates a `new Date` object by parsing the string representation of the `date` object

```
new Date(+date)
```

creates a `new Date` object from the timestamp obtained by converting the `date` object to a number

```
new Date(date.valueOf())
```

creates a `new Date` object from the timestamp obtained from the `date` object

The effect is the same, but this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/date-parse) seems to point to the third case as being the fastest on all the browsers i tested on. If the test cases are wrong (due to browser optimizations), please help by fixing them and commenting here!